# Why do we see the Stack Overflow survey?

Tags: discussion

Our sidebar prominently links to this year's SO Dev Survey. Why? We are not a programmer or developer community.

In addition, it's most certainly *not* an event of this site:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The technical explanation is that someone from Stack Exchange registered it as an event on Computer Science, using a [moderator tool](https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/community-events) that I'd forgotten existed, if I ever knew.

Part of me thinks that this is a mistake made by someone who saw “computer” in the name of the site and didn't read the second word — we do get many of these. And so the event should be removed.

Another part of me wants to encourage folks from outside Stack Overflow to participate, to remind Stack Exchange (oops, [they renamed themselves to Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)) that the world does not consist of English-speaking programmers.

Opinions?

Comment: We did our best to reach audiences within our network that we thought would be interested in taking the survey. No harm intended. If y'all, as a community, disagree, feel free to remove the event. You have the access and the power to do so.

Comment: @AdamLear Ultimately, it comes down to how you see this survey. Do you want to interview people in the software-making business? (The possible answers of Q5 "What do you consider yourself?" seem to suggest so.) Then the event should only be active on sites whose scope addresses such people -- not this site. If you want to find out how predominant which programming types are on the SE network as a whole, then the event should appear everywhere, but set up in a way that allows to say "I can't/don't program" or "it's a side hobby" or "it's a housework tool like hammer and nail for me".

Comment: @AdamLear I notice that the ad is still showing. Did you come to a conclusion that would conclude this thread here?

Comment: @Raphael Adam said that it's up to us to remove the ad if we want. I'd want to see more community input before I act. One argument for the relevance of the survey is that a majority of students of computer science (a significant part of our audience) will end up being programmers and hence candidates for SO Careers. If even [cstheory.se] (where SO Careers isn't relevant) hasn't removed the survey, I think we can keep it.

Comment: I can not form an opinion before @AdamLear answers the question of intent. With the survey as is, I don't see how to fill it in meaningfully without already being a professional programmer. (Regarding [cstheory.SE], I doubt they'd care.)

Comment: @Raphael I am a professional programmer, and there were questions I couldn't answer meaningfully. That's just because some questions and some answer sets were poorly chosen.

Comment: It must have been a flub, because it's not on SQA despite the fact that we directly deal with (certain types of) programming questions.